# VBNewLine after certain number of characters AND a given character

Tags: vb.net

All,
I developed a formatting/comma-delimiting application that turns a long string of numbers into the correct format for SQL queries.

For example:

```
101
102
103
104
105
```

Becomes:

```
('101','102','103','104','105')
```

It's a very useful tool, but lets say there are 500 different values to format.  This creates a very long line in SQL server.

I've been searching on the internet, but I have yet to find something that can accomplish my question:

How do I word wrap to 100 characters per line, but not breaking up the format:

```
('Value1','Value2','Value3')
```

Please let me know if I need to explain further.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have the function that converts it to the format for SQL queries? It'd be much easier for us help you if we knew what you were doing now and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: But why? SQL server doesn't care if the text is on one line or not.

Comment: @Mangus, Of course it doesn't.  This is to keep stored procedures and ad-hoc queries clean-looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will convert the "long string of numbers" into sql format with a `lineLength` parameter:

```
Public Function ConvertToSqlParameter(input As String, lineLength As Integer) As String
    Dim sb = New StringBuilder("(")
    Dim len = 0
    For Each s In input.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If len >= lineLength Then
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
            len = 0
        End If
        Dim str = "'" + s + "',"
        len += str.Length
        sb.Append(str)
    Next
    sb.Length -= 1
    sb.Append(")")
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```